# Unexpected identifier for function call

Tags: javascript

I have a simple onclick feature which calls a function but im getting an unexpected identifier but i don't see where the mistake is, it doesn't actually give me the error until i click the link which is confusing.

This is the script:

```
function discard_item(id,name){
 alert('test');
 return false;
} 

function load(){
   name = 'test';
   id = 1;
   output = [];

   output.push('[<a href="#" onclick="return discard_item("'+id+'","'+name+'")">Discard</a>]');

   document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = (output.join(''));

}

load();
```

When i click the link to call discard_item i get : Unexpected token }

Can't seem to see a mistake in my script though ?   http://jsfiddle.net/Lu2HK/6/

Hope you can help!

Comment: What is the square bracket inside the string passed to `push()` for? And you have to escape the quote inside the string or it will be incorrect: `onclick="return discard_item("id","name")"`

Comment: so the html will look like this [Discard] but only the word is clickable..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Try this:](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu2HK/13/)

Change the `"` to escaped `'`s:

```
output.push('[<a href="#" onclick="return discard_item(\''+id+'\',\''+name+'\')">Discard</a>]');
```

Comment: Do you only need to escape it on strings or on ints aswell ?

Comment: Numbers typically auto-convert to string unless there's other numbers in the mix, then make sure you do number ops in parens before adding to strings.